# Multi Store doesnt work - .htaccess?

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.2.2, server-setup

I created a multi store but I have a problem.

I use magento 1.9.2.2 - can you tell me if i need to modify the index.php and the htaccess?

I modified the htaccess as follows:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.magento\.zweitedomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=neuestorecode
SetEnvIf Host www\.magento\.zweitedomain\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^magento\.zweitedomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=neuestorecode
SetEnvIf Host ^magento\.zweitedomain\.de MAGE_RUN_TYPE=Website
```

The second domain points to the mainserver via a-Record and IPv4. But it doesnt work!

Do I need to make other changes? I read that the domain should Point to the document_root of the main store - is the way via a-Record enough?

I also tried to Change the index.php and added the following code above `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain.de': Mage::run('MEIN_STORECODE_DE','store'); break;
    case 'zweitedomain.de: Mage::run('MEIN_STORECODE','store'); break;
    case 'www.domain.de': Mage::run('MEIN_STORECODE_DE','store'); break;
    case 'www.zweitedomain.de': Mage::run('MEIN_STORECODE','store'); break;
    default: Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); break;
```

how to do setup of multi store?

Comment: Just to be sure, you *did* set the base url configuration for each website accordingly?

Comment: Yes, under > Configuration > select the New Store > Web > Secure and unsecure URL i Write in the Second Domain

Comment: Any ideas?:(...

Comment: Can you explain how exactly "it does not work"? What happens when you go to www.magento.zweitedomain.de ?

Comment: Hi, i made a mistake - it´s not magento.seconddomain. 
It´s a seperate Domain - so the htaccess code is 

SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
SetEnvIf Host \.seconddomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=code of second Website

If i want to open the second URL i get the Screen with the Information

Welcome to Second-Domain
This Website currently not exist

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to do any changes in `index.php`. An example apache configuration that you can add at the top of your `.htaccess` file is:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
SetEnvIf Host magento\.zweitedomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=zweitewebsite
```

(if `zweitewebsite` is the code of your second website)

I usally don't add the `^` and `$` delimiters, so that all subdomains or developer instances are matched as well as long the host contains "magento.zweitedomain.de":

- www.magento.zweitedomain.de
- test.magento.zweitedomain.de
- magento.zweitedomain.de.local

Comment: Hi, i made a mistake - it´s not magento.seconddomain. It´s a seperate Domain - so the htaccess code is SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website SetEnvIf Host \.seconddomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=code of second Website

 If i want to open the second URL i get the Screen with the Information Welcome to Second-Domain This Website currently not exist

When

Comment: Then "Point to the document_root of the main store" is exactly what you are missing. Configure your *web server* that the second domain shares the document root with the first domain (this is the virtual host configuration, how exactly you do it depends on your hoster)

Comment: Ok that means i Need to ask my actual hoster of the Shop how to share the document root of the main Website with the second Domain?

Comment: Yes, that would help.

Comment: Great - i will let you know if it works after this Change - Thx !

Comment: Hi, that´s it - the second Domain Point now to the root_document /magento/ - but if i want to open the second URL it redirect to the Main Domain.

i add in the top of the htaccess which is in the root folder:

SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
SetEnvIf Host \.seconddomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=storecodeofseconddomain

Comment: "storecodeofseconddomain" must be the code of the **website**. After the change, you have to clear your browser's cache because the redirect is cached.

Comment: It´s not working - it´s the same as before. I will try it in 2 hours again. Maybe i made a mistake.

Comment: Did i Need to Change something in httpd.conf ?

Comment: The Site was down before a few Minutes - After Clear the Cache via FTP it works again.
Someone Know what the Problem is?
I just modified the htaccess before a few Hours :(

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-30115556/image.png.html

Comment: Nobody an idea?....