# Magento cms home page and products not shown on the multi store website on different domain

Tags: multistore, magento-1, server-setup, multidomain

i m working on admin multisite magento installation which is not having its own frontend.
In this installation i have configured 2 websites store and store view.

Admin Magento installation is present on, for eg. domain1.com with directory structure like this .
`../public_html/magento_admin`

Please Note that Everything works fine when i configure store1 as directory like below

`../public_html/magento_admin/store1/` and

access with url `http://..../magento_admin/store1`

But problem arises when i configure the store1 on different domain for eg. domani2.com and access store1 by url `http://domain2.com/`

After configuring store1 for domain2.com theme, menus, header, footer is shown correctly, but the cms home page is not showing on the home page.
and if i click any category then it tells there is no product for corresponding selected product category. what may be wrong ?

For store1, i have set the skin, media, js to admin url like

`.../magento_admin/skin/`

`.../magento_admin/media/`

`.../magento_admin/js/`

and store1 base url to

`...domain2.com/`

i have copied the `.htaccess` and `index.php` file in root of `....domain2.com/`
and have changed following lines in `index.php`

```
$mageRunCode = 'store1_code';

$mageRunType = 'website';
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a different document root for domain1.com and domain2.com. As I understand you, the Magento installation is at `domain1/public_html/magento_admin`.

Then point the document root for domain2.com to this directory and instead of hard coding `MAGE_RUN_CODE` in `index.php`, set it based on the domain, as explained here: [Multi Store doesnt work - .htaccess?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107088/multistore-doesnt-work-htaccess/107209#107209)

> First of all, you don't need to do any changes in `index.php`. An
>   example apache configuration that you can add at the top of your
>   `.htaccess` file is:
>
> ```
> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
> SetEnvIf Host magento\.zweitedomain\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=zweitewebsite
> ```
>
> (if `zweitewebsite` is the code of your second website)
>
> I usally don't add the `^` and `$` delimiters, so that all subdomains
>   or developer instances are matched as well as long the host contains
>   "magento.zweitedomain.de":
>
> - www.magento.zweitedomain.de
> - test.magento.zweitedomain.de
> - magento.zweitedomain.de.local